# How to use rnfirebase analytics?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, react-native-firebase

I find a problem to create a screen analytics using rnfirebase version 5, I have followed this documentation https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/analytics/reference/analytics and this blog https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-firebase-analytics/, but the data not show in firebase like this :

[image]

this is my script :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

// export class
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen('HOME');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Firebase Analytics</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

please anyone help me to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: Did you enable Firebase analytics debug as the dev-yakuza tutorial recommends? Are you seeing native analytics logs in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine but you need to provide a second parameter to setCurrentScreen if you want to override the screen class : https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics#setCurrentScreen (this is for v6 but it was working the same in v5)

so you would have :

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen('HOME', 'HOME_SCREEN_CLASS');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, in the firebase still not set. Do yo have another idea ?